# Redirect Robot Framework Requests to OWASP ZAP

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework, owasp

my specific questions here are:

> 1. How to redirect RobotFramework requests to OWASP ZAP
> 2. How to forward OWASP ZAP response to RobotFramework

with note, for some reasons I dont wanna RobotFramework or OWASP ZAP to open any browser. So it should just RobotFramework - OWASP ZAP - web application communication line.

Comment: Can you configure Zap as a proxy? this is what I'm doing with Selenium